# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when trying to navigate through object. Blade - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm making a pdf report to download, this is the relevant data. I'm trying to navigate through but I'm having trouble

```
[ 
   { 
      "id":1,
      "name":"asdfasd",
      "description":"fasdfasdfafa",
      "user_id":1,
      "anonymous":0,
      "created_at":"2019-12-09 10:30:50",
      "updated_at":"2019-12-09 10:33:25",
      "survey_questions":[ 
         { 
            "id":1,
            "question":"asfdasdfsdf",
            "user_id":1,
            "survey_section_id":1,
            "response_type_id":1,
            "optional":0,
            "num":null,
            "rank":null,
            "show_text":0,
            "created_at":"2019-12-09 10:29:27",
            "updated_at":"2019-12-09 10:29:27",
            "pivot":{ 
               "survey_id":1,
               "survey_question_id":1
            }
         }
      ],
      "answer":[ 

      ],
      "evaluation":{ 
         "id":1,
         "survey_id":1,
         "init_date":"2019-12-04 00:00:00",
         "end_date":"2019-12-07 00:00:00",
         "report_date":"2019-12-08 00:00:00",
         "created_at":"2019-12-09 10:30:50",
         "updated_at":"2019-12-09 10:33:25",
         "evaluation_results":[ 

         ]
      }
   }
]
```

It's called `$survey`, I've tried doing a couple things

```
$survey->name; //works
$survey->survey_questions; //no result when there should be
$survey->evaluation; //works while the survey_questions doesn't
```

I would like to access the other stuff like `survey_questions, answer` and in turn access the stuff inside there.

When I try this I get the mentioned error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

```
@foreach($survey->survey_questions as $question)
   {{$question}}
@endforeach
```

This is how I'm sending the data from the controller

```
$survey = Survey::with('surveyQuestions', 'answer', 
'evaluation', 'evaluation.evaluationResults')
            ->where('id', $id)->first();

$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadView('pdf.report', ['survey' => $survey]);
return $pdf->stream();
```

What is the correct way to be able to access this data?

Comment: $survey is not the object you have encoded and posted, otherwise also the first won't work

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia what do you mean? I edited to show how I'm send the data

Comment: and if you json_encode the $survey it prints this?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia i did `{{$survey}}` and took the result and put it into a json formatter to better show the data

Comment: are you sure that $survey->name; is working fine?...

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia yea, it shows the correct name

Comment: please post the whole view, there is something wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203934/discussion-between-nancy-and-albertosinigaglia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have `surveyQuestions()` method define in Survey Model, If so then your `foreach` should be like

```
@foreach($survey->surveyQuestions as $question)
   {{$question}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your `first()` is giving you back an array (if all the code is the posted and there is no other pieces), but as you can see, in the JSON the first character is `[` and so the last is `]`, so what you are manipulating is an array. Not sure also how `$survey->name` is working for you, what you should do instead is access the array and than get the value you want:

```
$survey[0]->name;
@foreach($survey[0]->survey_questions as $question)
   {{$question}}
@endforeach
...
```

Comment: If I try this I get this error `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object` on `$survey[0]->name`

Comment: please post the view, or you have not post the correct json or you are doing something to $survey on the view

Answer (score 0):

You should send array to `foreach` but you sent `json`

Try

```
@foreach(json_decode ($survey->survey_questions,true) as $question)
   {{$question}}
@endforeach
```